# Is this Gallifreyan, and what does it say?

Tags: doctor-who

I came into work this morning (I am a graduate student at a department of astrophysics) and saw this drawn on one of the hallway chalkboards:

[image]

My mind immediately thought: that looks Gallifreyan!

Is it Gallifreyan?  And if so, what does it say?  If not, any ideas where to look for its meaning?

Note:  I realize that series 9 just started, and I have not yet seen the first episode of the series.  If this particular symbol is connected with this, I am okay with spoilers, but you probably should cover up the answer for others who are not okay with spoilers.

Comment: Does it mean No Spoilers? Was River Song there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, that is definitely something that resembles the Gallifreyan circular alphabet we've seen consistently on the recent series of *Doctor Who*.

As far as I know, there isn't any *official* translation of the alphabet; in fact, in at least one case ("A Good Man Goes To War") River Song explicitly mentions that High Gallifreyan writing "doesn't translate" -- even the TARDIS can't do it for someone who doesn't read it.

However, there have been many attempts by fans to scour the episodes looking for hints as to what certain words might mean, based on the writing in various places where The Doctor may have read or explained them.

The symbol on your chalkboard is one I've seen in a few different places; it appears to be a very close approximation of this fan-based word for "time". It's not exactly right, but it was also probably drawn from memory by a fan, so I think we can cut them some slack :)

(Again, this is all *non-canon*; as far as I know the writing on the show itself is just random cool-looking circular designs.)

[image]

Comment: I am checking a few obvious episodes to see if that symbol shows up on-screen anywhere but I suspect it was "invented" by fans trying to make a real language out of Gallifreyan.

Comment: It doesn't match up with TIME. Knowing the general mentality of college students, it's probably Gallifreyan for a rude phrase revolving around someone's mom.

Comment: "Time" was the closest one I could find; in particular the central circle with the three small arcs cut out and two other circles above it was rather unique.

Comment: given the above symbols and their meaning, it seems the  Gallifreyans could learn a thing or two about compressing their representations into a more compact format.  I would hate to take a test in this language, I probably wouldn't finish reading the first question until the test was half over, and would not have the first sentence of my answer done before time was up!

Comment: @Michael I have a strong suspicion they treat this type of writing the same way we treat calligraphy -- a really fancy, artsy type of writing that you don't usually bother with unless you're trying to be pretty.

Comment: How many different words, or inflections, or conjugations, or contrasubjunctations do you suppose Gallifreyans have for *"time"*?

Comment: Where do the images at the bottom of your answer come from?

Comment: I agree the symbol is most similar to 'time' but you should consider that the outer circle with a line through is like a 'no smoking' or 'no cycling' sign (and not part of the word) - in that context it means 'no time' or maybe a more literal interpretation would be 'no gallifreyan' or 'no speaking/talking' (which makes sense in a hallway with lots of 'smart people' who will recognize the language style even if the word is non-sense)

Answer (score 2):

No. It looks like a standard "not permitted" strikethrough of the game Downfall:

[image]

Clearly your department has a problem with people playing this game in that area, and has decided to ban it.

I remember it being quite clacketty, so it could easily be a distraction to people trying to work.

-*cough*-

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not Gallifreyan.

It looks like it's supposed to be, but it isn't. Its like non-Japanese trying to write what looks like Japanese.

It's poorly written, but I translate it to:

> ttt
>
> ati
>
> t
>
> t

Correctly written that should look like this:

[image: badly written gallifreyan]

If you're interested to learn Gallifreyan, here is a [good crash course](http://io9.com/learn-to-write-gallifreyan-in-9-simple-steps-506989915). If you're interested in seeing your name in Gallifreyan [go here](https://gallifreyan-9000.rhcloud.com/#YOUR%20NAME).

Note: Answer non-canon

Comment: I don't see it. Other than the outer circle, what does this drawing have in common with the one in the question?

Comment: Just in case someone is confused: that is *one fan's idea* of what Gallifreyan might look like. As there *is no* official Gallifreyan language, any one fan's idea is as valid as any other :)

Comment: You're saying A) it's not Gallifreyan, B) what it isn't in Gallifreyan, and C) what it should be? WHAT **WHAT** SHOULD BE?? ttt ati t t? How is this an answer? Please, *please,* explain your thinking here.

Comment: It's college. It's probably one Whovian sending a secret message to another Whovian: "Ta-ta's at 2 o'clock".

Comment: @MeatTrademark The answer is No, it's not Gallifreyan as understood by humanity. But it almost could be translated as above.

Comment: @MrLister Gallifreyan is normally read as an entire sentence in a circle, with each inner circle being a word. In this case 2 of the inner circles are concentric rather than rotated. The inner word is 3 inner curves ("T"s). The middle circle is touching 2 cirlces ("A"s), one with a line (making it an "I") extending and on inner curve ("T"). Then there are 2 outer circles with inner curves ("T"s).